# mxArrayToString() function in Matlab

Tags: c, matlab, mex

Does this code

```
argv[i] = mxArrayToString( prhs[i] );
```

convert the inputs to strings and save it in the argv[] array?

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    int argc = 0;
    char **argv;
    int i, result;

    argc = nrhs;
    argv = (char **) mxCalloc( argc, sizeof(char *) );
    for (i = 0; i < nrhs; i++){
        argv[i] = mxArrayToString( prhs[i] );

//     ...


}


// ...
```

Is it possible to improved it for better performance?

Comment: No, it does not convert to string, it only works if the mxArray is a string. Please read the docs for questions like these: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxarraytostring.html

Comment: @CrisLuengo -  From the link you provided, the statement _Call mxArrayToString to copy the character data of an mxCHAR array into a C-style string._ on the surface seems to contradict what you have asserted.  For clarity, can you please reiterate?  i.e. what is wrong with what OP passes as argument in that function?

Comment: @ryyker: To clarify: it doesn't convert an arbitrary input to string. It converts a MATLAB string to a C string.